# Best alternative for jQuery toggle() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery deprecated toggle() method. It was way to easy to toggle classes, While searching stackoverflow I found various other methods to accomplish the same task( [Alternative to jQuery's .toggle() method that supports eventData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459153/alternative-to-jquerys-toggle-method-that-supports-eventdata) ). Which jQuery snippet should be ideal to switch classes for this markup?

Thanks

Markup:

```
<a href="#">Toggle Class</a>
<div class="a"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.a{
background: #f2f2f2;
}
.b{
background: #ededed;
}
```

Comment: why not use `.toggleClass()` ? `toggle()` is only deprecated from binding events not from hiding and showing and `.toggleClass` is not deprecated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle between two classes in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644545/toggle-between-two-classes-in-jquery)

Comment: The selected duplicate is NOT a duplicate of this question, it actually suggests using the very code this question is trying to replace. I'm sure there is an exact duplicate though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, simply use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass).

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("div").toggleClass("a b");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

`toggleClass()` seems to be what you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 class to toggle (enabling and removing it), below should work fine:

```
$("a").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('class1', '');
});
```

Comment: or just `$(this).toggleClass('class1')`

Answer (score 0):

`toggle()` function used to toggle view.
Which has performance issues.(will recommend not to use)

`toggleClass()` is used to toggle class.

case:1

```
<div id='mydiv' class="class1"></div>

$('#mydiv').toggleClass('class1 class2');

output: <div id='mydiv' class="class2"></div>
```

case:2

```
<div id='mydiv' class="class2"></div>

$('#mydiv').toggleClass('class1 class2');

output: <div id='mydiv' class="class1"></div>
```

case:3

```
<div id='mydiv' class="class1 class2 class3"></div>

$('#mydiv').toggleClass('class1 class2');

output: <div id='mydiv' class="class3"></div>
```