# to image click I gave a function, on clicking it am getting image id, using this I have to change the image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I gave a function, on clicking it am getting image id, using this I have to change the image using javascript.

The code is as follows

```
$('img').live('click', function () {
     alert(this.id);
 });
```

the outputs are as follows like_0,like_1......
and unlike_0,unlike_1.........

But depending on the output I have to change image

```
$("#like_").click(function () {
    $("#tipid").val(1);
    $("#like_").attr("src", "images/ic_like_select.png");
    $("#unlike_").attr("src", "images/ic_unlike_unselect.png");
});
$("#unlike_").click(function () {
    $("#tipid").val(0);
    $("#like_").attr("src", "images/ic_like_unselect.png");
    $("#unlike_").attr("src", "images/ic_unlike_select.png");
});
```

My problem is I was not known how to change. 
Can someone help me thanks.

Comment: FYI, don't use `live` it is deprecated method. Use `on` instead.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle, your question is not clear..

Comment: Update the Question with HTML Code  too.

Comment: @VisioN you should ask which version of jQuery he is using first. And then suggest. Because he have output of alert it means it works for him. :)

Comment: @antindexer It is always good to be upgraded.

Comment: You can add data attributes to your elements to detect their current state. based on the value of the data attribute you could then select the image you want on the element (or do something similar using classes)

Comment: @VisioN sometimes you cannot simply upgrade if you are using some old project code. Which can cause a lot of refracting.

Comment: @antindexer jQuery 1.7 which supports `on` was released in November 2011 (more than 2 years ago). A lot of methods have been refactored and accelerated.  *"Working"* is not always the matter: `live` was deprecated, since it is much less effective than `on` having event delegation from the closest static parent element.

Comment: can you please say how can i change the image src

Comment: @VisioN why you are explaining all about this to me? You are smart. Do you? If you are smart person your actions should be also smart. Not just give simple answers like OP is .... In first place try to understand others. And show your smartness and respect.

Comment: please tell me how can i change the image source please

Comment: Check my answer. Hope it may help you get your requirement served.

Comment: i found solution thanks to evryone

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at the toggle function from jquery

```
x.toggle(function(){}, function(){})
```

something similar has been done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644545/toggle-between-two-classes-in-jquery)!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to change your image, and you have to change it depending on the id.

I'll explain what I'd try in your place:

Let's supose this is the picture I want to change:

```
<img id='like_0' src='/path/to/image' />
```

So, once you have the id of this image (like_0) you could try this in your javascript function:

```
document.getElementById("like_0").src="../path/new_img.png";
```

This last instruction changes the path of the image to the new one

Comment: but in the similar way i have to change for others also that is like_0,like_1,like_2.......

Answer (score -1):

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq9T7/)**

```
like_img="like_url";
unlike_img="unlike_url";

toggle=function(){
    if($(this).attr("id").match(/^like_/)!=null)
    {
        if($("#tipid").val()==0)
        {
            $("#tipid").val(1);
            $("[id^=like_]").attr('src', unlike_img);
            $("[id^=unlike_]").attr('src', like_img);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#tipid").val(0);
            $("[id^=like_]").attr('src', like_img);
            $("[id^=unlike_]").attr('src', unlike_img);        
        }
    }
    if($(this).attr("id").match(/^unlike_/)!=null)
    {
        if($("#tipid").val()==1)
        {
            $("#tipid").val(0);
            $("[id^=unlike_]").attr('src', like_img);
            $("[id^=like_]").attr('src', unlike_img);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#tipid").val(1);
            $("[id^=unlike_]").attr('src', unlike_img);
            $("[id^=like_]").attr('src', like_img);        
        }
    }
}

$('img').on('click', toggle);
```

Your question seemed not clear enough. Still I think the demo may help you.

Comment: Downvote, What's the reason? please let me improve my answer.