# Jquery : Toggle DIV Class name in every second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two  DIV class : demo1 and demo2

```
<div class="demo1">example text</div>
```

so How can i change div class name with every second : **demo1  to demo2** and **demo2 to demo1**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle between two classes in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644545/toggle-between-two-classes-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) with [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $div = $('.demo1');
    setInterval(function () {
        $div.toggleClass('demo1 demo2');
    }, 1000);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D7XsJ/)